# Inno Setup query Windows service status

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to find a way of querying the status of a Windows service i.e. whether it is Running, Stopped or Disabled. I know I can use `sc.exe query ServiceName`, but this would involve using a batch file to find the status in the output, piping to a file and then reading this in, which seems a little convoluted. I have found the following [Windows API function on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which I believe will probably do what I want, but am not sure how or if this could be incorporated into Inno Setup. Alternatively, is there another method that could be used for returning the status of a Windows service natively with Inno Setup?

Comment: What is *disabled* state ? Service state can be just one of the following Stopped, Start pending, Stop pending, Running, Continue pending, Pause pending, Paused.

Comment: As the name suggests, the service has been disabled i.e. Startup Type has been changed from Automatic or Manual to Disabled, so the service does not run. I am still trying to find a reliable way of detecting the Windows Firewall state (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039971/inno-setup-detect-windows-firewall-state) and it appears that if the Windows Firewall service has been disabled, no matter what you read from the Registry, the Windows Firewall will be inactive.

Comment: It appears that the query may actually need to check the Startup Type as well as it being Stopped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WinAPI is the best way you can choose to control services from Inno Setup so far. For your purpose is enough to use the [`QueryServiceStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939(v=vs.85).aspx) function. It has been superseded by the `Ex` version just to return things that you don't need for your task; it's not deprecated. The following code uses the lowest necessary [access rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx), so it can run even without admin elevation:

```
[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

const
  SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = $0001;

  SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = $0004;

  SERVICE_STOPPED = $00000001;
  SERVICE_START_PENDING = $00000002;
  SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = $00000003;
  SERVICE_RUNNING = $00000004;
  SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = $00000005;
  SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = $00000006;
  SERVICE_PAUSED = $00000007;

type
  TSCHandle = THandle;

  TServiceStatus = record
    dwServiceType: DWORD;
    dwCurrentState: DWORD;
    dwControlsAccepted: DWORD;
    dwWin32ExitCode: DWORD;
    dwServiceSpecificExitCode: DWORD;
    dwCheckPoint: DWORD;
    dwWaitHint: DWORD;
  end;

function OpenService(hSCManager: TSCHandle; lpServiceName: string;
  dwDesiredAccess: DWORD): TSCHandle;
  external 'OpenService{#AW}@advapi32.dll stdcall';
function OpenSCManager(lpMachineName: string; lpDatabaseName: string;
  dwDesiredAccess: DWORD): TSCHandle;
  external 'OpenSCManager{#AW}@advapi32.dll stdcall';
function QueryServiceStatus(hService: TSCHandle;
  out lpServiceStatus: TServiceStatus): BOOL;
  external 'QueryServiceStatus@advapi32.dll stdcall';
function CloseServiceHandle(hSCObject: TSCHandle): BOOL;
  external 'CloseServiceHandle@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function GetServiceState(const SvcName: string): DWORD;
var
  Status: TServiceStatus;
  Manager: TSCHandle;
  Service: TSCHandle;
begin
  // open service manager with the lowest required access rights for this task
  Manager := OpenSCManager('', '', SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if Manager <> 0 then
  try
    // open service with the only required access right needed for this task
    Service := OpenService(Manager, SvcName, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if Service <> 0 then
    try
      // and query service status
      if QueryServiceStatus(Service, Status) then
        Result := Status.dwCurrentState
      else
        RaiseException('QueryServiceStatus failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError));
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(Service);
    end
    else
      RaiseException('OpenService failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError));
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(Manager);
  end
  else
    RaiseException('OpenSCManager failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError));
end;
```

An example usage:

```
try
  case GetServiceState('netman') of
    SERVICE_STOPPED: MsgBox('The service is not running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    SERVICE_START_PENDING: MsgBox('The service is starting.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING: MsgBox('The service is stopping.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    SERVICE_RUNNING: MsgBox('The service is running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING: MsgBox('The service continue is pending.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING: MsgBox('The service pause is pending.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    SERVICE_PAUSED: MsgBox('The service is paused.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  else
    RaiseException('GetServiceState returned unknown state.');
  end;
except
  MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Or without reporting what has failed you can write a function like this:

```
function TryGetServiceState(const SvcName: string; out State: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  Status: TServiceStatus;
  Manager: TSCHandle;
  Service: TSCHandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  Manager := OpenSCManager('', '', SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if Manager <> 0 then
  begin
    Service := OpenService(Manager, SvcName, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if Service <> 0 then
    begin
      if QueryServiceStatus(Service, Status) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        State := Status.dwCurrentState;
      end;
      CloseServiceHandle(Service);
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle(Manager);
  end;
end;
```

And possible usage:

```
var
  State: DWORD;
begin
  if TryGetServiceState('netman', State) then
  begin
    case State of
      SERVICE_STOPPED: MsgBox('The service is not running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SERVICE_START_PENDING: MsgBox('The service is starting.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SERVICE_STOP_PENDING: MsgBox('The service is stopping.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SERVICE_RUNNING: MsgBox('The service is running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING: MsgBox('The service continue is pending.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING: MsgBox('The service pause is pending.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SERVICE_PAUSED: MsgBox('The service is paused.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    else
      MsgBox('GetServiceState returned unknown state.', mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end
  else
    MsgBox('Something failed during service state checking.', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @TLama. Please see above comments regarding Disabled. Is this able to check the Startup Type being set to Disabled also?

Comment: No problem. Would you mind if that will be in a single function ? I feel no good to *bother* service manager twice to query different things.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. I simply need to check if 'MpsSvc' (the Windows Firewall service) is Stopped and Disabled.

Comment: Just wondering if you had further information on how to check if the Startup Type is set to Disabled as well as the Service Status being Stopped. Many thanks.

Comment: I was wrong. It's not easy to process result from the `QueryServiceConfig` function from Pascal Script (fortunately the member you need is on fixed place). Try [this script](http://pastebin.com/zniNebJs) (you can merge it into a single one, just combine the access rights).

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a compile error complaining about `Unknown identifier 'QueryServiceConfig'` in your Pastebin script. Is this a function that needs to be defined?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to paste the function prototype. See that code again ;)

Comment: Thanks. Working perfectly now. :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Btw. that buffer insanity is there because you cannot allocate a block of memory with a subsequent structure typecast in Pascal Script. But anyway, I'm considering contribution of a few service handling functions to the Inno Setup itself as it's quite frequently asked topic (but the implementation is not so easy, e.g. controlling services should run in a background thread while showing some progress etc. so cannot tell if such proposal will be accepted).

Comment: It would definitely be most useful to have some Windows Service functions included with Inno Setup. In fact there are many functions, some extremely simple, that I have either created myself or found in the Public Domain or from people's help on here, that would be useful to have built-in. How does one go about contributing code? Is their an FAQ somewhere?

Comment: [There is](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-new-code-translations-or-documentation-updates), but note that it's not easy. For instance stopping (or pausing, starting) needs some time (that you can only suggest), and how would one implement e.g. starting a service in a function ? Would you suddenly show an extra marquee progress bar dialog, or a wizard page when such function would be called ?

Answer (score 4):

> Alternatively, is there another method that could be used for returning the status of a Windows service natively with Inno Setup?

InnoSetup doesn't provide a native method to check the installation / run state of a service.

> I have found the following Windows API function on MSDN, which I believe will probably do what I want, but am not sure how or if this could be incorporated into Inno Setup.

Yes, there is some old code flying around over at [vincenzo.net](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Service_-_Functions_to_Start%2C_Stop%2C_Install%2C_Remove_a_Service) which makes use of `QueryServiceStatus()`. Feel free to adapt the code to your needs. I have not tested it.

```
[Code]
// function IsServiceInstalled(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
// function IsServiceRunning(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
// function InstallService(FileName, ServiceName, DisplayName, Description : string;ServiceType,StartType :cardinal) : boolean;
// function RemoveService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
// function StartService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
// function StopService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
// function SetupService(service, port, comment: string) : boolean;

type
    SERVICE_STATUS = record
        dwServiceType               : cardinal;
        dwCurrentState              : cardinal;
        dwControlsAccepted          : cardinal;
        dwWin32ExitCode             : cardinal;
        dwServiceSpecificExitCode   : cardinal;
        dwCheckPoint                : cardinal;
        dwWaitHint                  : cardinal;
    end;
    HANDLE = cardinal;

const
    SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG        = $1;
    SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG       = $2;
    SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS        = $4;
    SERVICE_START               = $10;
    SERVICE_STOP                = $20;
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS          = $f01ff;
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS       = $f003f;
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS   = $10;
    SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS = $20;
    SERVICE_WIN32               = $30;
    SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = $100;
    SERVICE_BOOT_START          = $0;
    SERVICE_SYSTEM_START        = $1;
    SERVICE_AUTO_START          = $2;
    SERVICE_DEMAND_START        = $3;
    SERVICE_DISABLED            = $4;
    SERVICE_DELETE              = $10000;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP        = $1;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE       = $2;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE    = $3;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE = $4;
    SERVICE_STOPPED             = $1;
    SERVICE_START_PENDING       = $2;
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING        = $3;
    SERVICE_RUNNING             = $4;
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING    = $5;
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING       = $6;
    SERVICE_PAUSED              = $7;

// #######################################################################################
// nt based service utilities
// #######################################################################################
function OpenSCManager(lpMachineName, lpDatabaseName: string; dwDesiredAccess :cardinal): HANDLE;
external 'OpenSCManagerA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function OpenService(hSCManager :HANDLE;lpServiceName: string; dwDesiredAccess :cardinal): HANDLE;
external 'OpenServiceA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function CloseServiceHandle(hSCObject :HANDLE): boolean;
external 'CloseServiceHandle@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function CreateService(hSCManager :HANDLE;lpServiceName, lpDisplayName: string;dwDesiredAccess,dwServiceType,dwStartType,dwErrorControl: cardinal;lpBinaryPathName,lpLoadOrderGroup: String; lpdwTagId : cardinal;lpDependencies,lpServiceStartName,lpPassword :string): cardinal;
external 'CreateServiceA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function DeleteService(hService :HANDLE): boolean;
external 'DeleteService@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function StartNTService(hService :HANDLE;dwNumServiceArgs : cardinal;lpServiceArgVectors : cardinal) : boolean;
external 'StartServiceA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function ControlService(hService :HANDLE; dwControl :cardinal;var ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'ControlService@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function QueryServiceStatus(hService :HANDLE;var ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'QueryServiceStatus@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function QueryServiceStatusEx(hService :HANDLE;ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'QueryServiceStatus@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function GetLastError() : cardinal;
external 'GetLastError@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function OpenServiceManager() : HANDLE;
begin
    if UsingWinNT() = true then begin
        Result := OpenSCManager('','',SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
        if Result = 0 then
            MsgBox('the servicemanager is not available', mbError, MB_OK)
    end
    else begin
            MsgBox('only nt based systems support services', mbError, MB_OK)
            Result := 0;
    end
end;

function IsServiceInstalled(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := true;
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;

function InstallService(FileName, ServiceName, DisplayName, Description : string;ServiceType,StartType :cardinal) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := CreateService(hSCM,ServiceName,DisplayName,SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,ServiceType,StartType,0,FileName,'',0,'','','');
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := true;
            // Win2K & WinXP supports aditional description text for services
            if Description<> '' then
                RegWriteStringValue(HKLM,'System\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + ServiceName,'Description',Description);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;

function RemoveService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_DELETE);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := DeleteService(hService);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;

function StartService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_START);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := StartNTService(hService,0,0);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end;
end;

function StopService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
    Status  : SERVICE_STATUS;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_STOP);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := ControlService(hService,SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP,Status);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end;
end;

function IsServiceRunning(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
    Status  : SERVICE_STATUS;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            if QueryServiceStatus(hService,Status) then begin
                Result :=(Status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING)
            end;
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
            end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;
```

My suggestion is to put the code into an external iss file (service.iss) and then #include it. This will keep the code section of the installer itself a bit cleaner.

Usage:

```
function InitializeSetup(): boolean;
begin
    if IsServiceInstalled('myservice') = false then begin
        if InstallService('c:\winnt\system32\myservice.exe','myservice','my service','my service is doing usefull things',SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_AUTO_START) = true then begin
            StartService('myservice');
            StopService('myservice');
            // after stopping a service you should wait some seconds before removing
            RemoveService('myservice');
            // otherwise removing can fail
        end
    end
    else if IsServiceRunning('myservice') then
        MsgBox('myservice is running',mbInformation, MB_OK);

    Result := false
end;
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning this requires ANSI Inno Setup.

Comment: It is compatibile with Unicode version changeing OpenSCManagerA dll import with OpenSCManagerW, CreateServiceA with CreateServiceW and so on

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just replace A with W on method names (all from `winsvc.h`).